# How should I process Kafka data?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I’m an absolute beginner in Kafka. Seeking experts opinion.

Using  Kafka Rest Proxy I'm writing to a topic . Data is in JSON .

```
{
  "value": {
  "record_id": 12345,
  "record_val": "Kolkata"
  }
}
```

1000/Sec JSON record will be inserted to the topic .

I would like to have 2 Kafka consumer.
In first consumer the latest value of given "record_id" in the topic is required.
Any given time the topic consist of the given JSON values.

```
{
  "value": {
  "record_id": 12345,
  "record_val": "Delhi"
  }
}

{
  "value": {
  "record_id": 12346,
  "record_val": "Durgapur"
  }
}

{
  "value": {
  "record_id": 12346,
  "record_val": "Kolkata"
  }
}
{
  "value": {
  "record_id": 12347,
  "record_val": "Blore"
  }
}
{
  "value": {
  "record_id": 12345,
  "record_val": "Mumbai"
  }
}

{
  "value": {
  "record_id": 12345,
  "record_val": "Kolkata"
  }
}
```

Now in consumer side I would like to get  latest value of any given "record_id"  e.g 12345 . So the result should be "Kolkata".

For the second consumer all the value of given "record_id" in the topic is required. e.g. for "record_id" 12345 the result should be

```
"Kolkata"
"Mumbai"
"Delhi"
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: `SELECT record_val FROM topic WHERE record_id = 12345` ?

Comment: Does Kafka support SQL query? reference please.

Comment: you have `kafka-connect` added as a tag.. So their documentation should suffice.. : https://github.com/datamountaineer/kafka-connect-query-language

Comment: That's not the use case for kafka. Consumer wouldn't have conditional logic. It will poll from the queue based on offset. You would need to handle that in your application logic.